# how to make django project click on a particular tab of a url

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am developing a code using python and Django for web scraping. I have provided the required url and already fetched the data.
But there is a tab on the url saying "show more results".
How can I make my Django project to click on that tab of "show more results" on the url and the fetch the new results now.

I have used Beautiful Soup library for web scraping/

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is an HTML parser and nothing more, if you want to automate clicking and so on you have to use other tools such as selenium.

Another idea might be getting the URL of "Show more results" and scrape the stuff that it loads. I assume it is loading the thing dynamically so look at your Network Tab (Ctrl+Shift+i then Network) and see which URL it is loading you may be able to scrape it.

Comment: Can you please help me as to how can I use selenium for the same as I have tried the Networking Tab but couldn't find anything significant.

Comment: Here is how: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ and for the Networking Tab, open it and when you click on Show More Results it should make an request to somewhere you can look onto that request and eventually scrape from there.

Comment: Can you please help me where I should look exactly in the documents 'selenium-python.readthedocs.io'. I am alone working on this project and on a tight schedule and have been exhausted.